# In my app, i'm able to go to gallery but after picking image, it is NOT going to "OnActivityResult" override method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change the profile pic and cover pic in my app. Everything is fine in my code except my cover and profile pics are not getting changed.

Here is my code file attached.

In my app, i'm able to go to gallery but after picking image it is NOT going to "OnActivityResult" override method. Though it stays on ProfileFragment activity but it does not go to OnActivityResult method.
In ProfileFragment, it never goes to 'OnActivityResult' method. And RESULT_OK is always -1.

Here is my ProfileActivity.java

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private TextView welcomeUserTv;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
     List<MenuModel> headerList = new ArrayList<>();
     HashMap<MenuModel, List<MenuModel>> childList = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        Toolbar mtoolbar_3p = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_3p);
        setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar_3p);

        expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.expNav_3p);

        DrawerLayout drawer_3p = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_3p);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle_3p = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer_3p, mtoolbar_3p, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        if (drawer_3p != null) {
            drawer_3p.addDrawerListener(toggle_3p);
        }
        toggle_3p.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navView_3p);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        checkUserStatus();

        //Bottom Navigation
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(selectedListener);
        //Home fragment transaction, Default on Startup
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        FragmentTransaction pft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        pft1.replace(R.id.content_frameLayout_inProfile, profileFragment, "");
        pft1.commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener selectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            //FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case (R.id.bottom_home):
                    //Home Fragment Transaction
                    //actionBar.setTitle("Home");
                    /*final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav_header_profile, null);
                    //set up for model selection
                    TextView modelTextview = addView.findViewById(R.id.welcomeUser);
                    modelTextview.setText(user.getEmail());*/
                    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction hft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    hft1.replace(R.id.content_frameLayout_inProfile, homeFragment, "");
                    hft1.commit();
                    return true;
                case (R.id.bottom_profile):
                    //Profile Fragment Transaction
                    //actionBar.setTitle("Profile");
                    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction pft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    pft1.replace(R.id.content_frameLayout_inProfile, profileFragment, "");
                    pft1.commit();
                    return true;
                case (R.id.bottom_mylist):
                    //MyList Fragment transaction
                    //actionBar.setTitle("My List");
                    MyListFragment mylistFragment = new MyListFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction mlft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    mlft1.replace(R.id.content_frameLayout_inProfile, mylistFragment, "");
                    mlft1.commit();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_logout,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_logout) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You've been logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            checkUserStatus();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void checkUserStatus() {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(user != null) {
            //mProfileTv.setText(user.getEmail());
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Your Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not Your Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        checkUserStatus();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_3p);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And here is my ProfileFragment.java code

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    //Firebase auth
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    //Firebase storage
    StorageReference storageReference;
    //path where images of user profile and cover will be stored
    String storagePath = "Users_Profile_Cover_Imgs/";

    //Views from xml
    ImageView mavatarTv, mcoverPic;
    TextView mnameTv, memailTv, mphoneTv;
    FloatingActionButton mfab;

    //Progress Dialog
    ProgressDialog pd;

    //Permissions constant
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE = 300;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE = 400;

    //Arrays of permission to be required
    String cameraPermission[];
    String storagePermission[];

    //uri of picked image
    Uri image_uri;

    String profileOrCoverPhoto;

    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");
        storageReference = getInstance().getReference();

        //init arrays of permission
        cameraPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        storagePermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        //init views
        mavatarTv = view.findViewById(R.id.avatarTv);
        mcoverPic = view.findViewById(R.id.coverPic);
        memailTv = view.findViewById(R.id.emailTv);
        mphoneTv = view.findViewById(R.id.phoneTv);
        mnameTv = view.findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
        mfab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);

        //init progress dialog
        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.getEmail());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //check until required data get
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String name = ""+ ds.child("name").getValue();
                    String email = ""+ ds.child("email").getValue();
                    String phone = ""+ ds.child("phone").getValue();
                    String image = ""+ ds.child("image").getValue();
                    String cover = ""+ ds.child("cover").getValue();
                    //set data
                    mnameTv.setText(name);
                    memailTv.setText(email);
                    mphoneTv.setText(phone);
                    try {
                        //If image is received then
                        Picasso.get().load(image).into(mavatarTv);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_default_img_white).into(mavatarTv);
                    }
                    try {
                        //If image is received then
                        Picasso.get().load(cover).into(mcoverPic);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //Fab button click
        mfab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showEditProfileDialog();
            }
        });


        return view;

    }

    private boolean checkStoragePermission() {
        //Check if storage permission is enabled or not
        //return true if enabled else false
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    return result;
    }

    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        //request runtime storage permission
        requestPermissions(storagePermission, STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private boolean checkCameraPermission() {
        //Check if storage permission is enabled or not
        //return true if enabled else false
        boolean result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        boolean result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result1 && result2;
    }

    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        //request runtime storage permission
        requestPermissions(cameraPermission, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void showEditProfileDialog() {
        //Show Dialog containing options: 1.Edit ProfilePic, 2. Edit cover, 3. Edit name, 4. Edit Phone

        //Options to show in dialog
        String[] options = {"Edit Profile Picture", "Edit Cover Picture", "Edit Name", "Edit Phone Number"};
        //alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //set title
        builder.setTitle("Choose Action");
        //set items to dialog
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(which == 0) {
                    //Edit Profile pic
                    pd.setMessage("Updating Profile picture");
                    profileOrCoverPhoto = "image"; //i.e, changing profile pic, make sure to assign same value
                    showImagePicDialog();
                }
                else if (which == 1) {
                    //Edit cover pic
                    pd.setMessage("Updating Cover Picture");
                    profileOrCoverPhoto = "cover"; //i.e, changing profile pic, make sure to assign same value
                    showImagePicDialog();
                }
                else if (which == 2) {
                    //Edit name pic
                    pd.setMessage("Updating Name");
                    showNamePhoneUpdateDialog("name");
                }
                else if (which == 3) {
                    //Edit phone pic
                    pd.setMessage("Updating Phone number ");
                    showNamePhoneUpdateDialog("phone");
                }
            }
        });
        //create n show dialog
        builder.create().show();

    }

    private void showNamePhoneUpdateDialog(final String key) {
        //
        //Custom dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Update "+key);
        //set layout of dialog
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        //add edit text
        final EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
        editText.setHint("Enter "+key);
        linearLayout.addView(editText);

        builder.setView(linearLayout);
        //Adding buttons to update
        builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String value = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                //validate
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
                    pd.show();
                    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                    result.put(key, value);
                    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(result)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Updated...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter "+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        //Adding buttons to cancel
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }

    private void showImagePicDialog() {
        //Show dialog containing options camera and gallery to pic the image
        //Options to show in dialog
        String[] options = {"Camera", "Gallery"};
        //alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //set title
        builder.setTitle("Pick Image From");
        //set items to dialog
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(which == 0) {
                    //Camera clicked (Permission required)
                    if (!checkCameraPermission()) {
                        requestCameraPermission();
                    } else {
                        pickFromCamera();
                    }
                }
                else if (which == 1) {
                    //Gallery clicked (Permission required)
                    if (!checkStoragePermission()) {
                        requestStoragePermission();
                    } else {
                        pickFromGallery();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //create n show dialog
        builder.create().show();
    }
    //First check firebase storage rules

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        //This method called when user press allow or deny from permission request dialog
        //here we'll handle permission cases
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE: {
                //picking from camera, 1st check camera n storage permission allowed or not
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean writeStorageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (cameraAccepted && writeStorageAccepted) {
                        //Permission enabled
                        pickFromCamera();
                    }
                    else {
                        //Permission denied
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enable Camera & Storage permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
            case STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE: {
                //picking from gallery, 1st check storage permission allowed or not
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean writeStorageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (writeStorageAccepted) {
                        //Permission enabled
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "req code:"+requestCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println("req code:"+requestCode);
                        pickFromGallery();
                    }
                    else {
                        //Permission denied
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enable Storage permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_OK ) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OnActivityResult method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE) {
                //image is picked from gallery, get uri of image
                image_uri = data.getData();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gallery Pic Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                uploadProfileCoverPhoto(image_uri);
            }
            /*if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE) {
                //image is picked from gallery, get uri of image
                image_uri = data.getData();
                uploadProfileCoverPhoto(image_uri);
            }*/
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void uploadProfileCoverPhoto(Uri uri) {
        pd.show();

        String filePathNName = storagePath+ ""+ profileOrCoverPhoto+ ""+ user.getUid();
        StorageReference storageReference2nd = storageReference.child(filePathNName);
        storageReference2nd.putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //image is uploaded to storage, now gets its url and store in usrs database
                        Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());
                        Uri downloadUri = uriTask.getResult();

                        //check if image is uploaded or not and url is received
                        if(uriTask.isSuccessful()) {
                            //image uploaded, so add/update url in users db
                            HashMap<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();

                            results.put(profileOrCoverPhoto, downloadUri.toString());
                            databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(results)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            pd.dismiss(); //image url in db of user added
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Updated...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            pd.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error updating image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void pickFromCamera() {
        //intent of picking image from device camera
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Temp Pic");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Temp Description");

        //put image uri
        image_uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        //Intent to start camera
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);
    }

    private void pickFromGallery() {
        //pick from gallery
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        //Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gallery Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("Hello Gallery: "+getTargetRequestCode()+" result_ok:"+RESULT_OK);

        //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        //getParent().startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY);


    }
}
```

All imports are proper.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shortlisted">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".InfoActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: where is requestPermissions() ?

Comment: Now, it realized my mistake. it was silly mistake but a bit difficult to find. Actually I had written "requestCode" instead of "resultCode" in OnActivityResult method of ProfileFragment. Thanx anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Try to override onActivityResult method in ProfileActivity.

What happens is that the onActivityResult method of your ProfileActivity is called first. So when you override the method in ProfileActivity, it calls super() which in turn gives the appropriate fragment the result.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

After discussion with my friend, Now I have found my silly mistake. it was silly mistake but a bit difficult to find. Actually I had written "requestCode" instead of "resultCode" in OnActivityResult method of ProfileFragment. Thanx anyway all mates..